# Linux disappeared after installing Windows 10 but not as dual boot

Tags: linux, dual-boot, boot-loader

I wanted to try Linux and got Linux mint 19.3 on my computer. After that I needed some windows apps and set up windows 10 **but not as dual boot** so the Linux disappeared. Is there a way to restore Linux and have the same two systems on my machine. Thanks for help

Comment: Ordering is important for dual boot. Windows isn't aware of other OSes, nor takes care to preserve them. Thus, Windows needs to be installed first, then GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you let the Windows installer to overwrite the whole disk, then I'm afraid Linux is completely destroyed (and you'll need to reinstall it if you want dual boot). If you are lucky, you might be able to recover some of your Linux files using a data recovery software like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or similar.

But if you told the Windows installer to only use the free (unpartitioned) space, then most likely only the bootloader has been replaced. That's a lot easier to fix.

If your system uses UEFI, it might be simple to fix: just go into BIOS settings, and change the boot order to make "Mint" (or something similar) the highest-priority boot target instead of "Windows Boot Manager", and you will get back to Linux. Then make sure you have the `os-prober` package installed, and run `sudo update-grub`. It should detect the presence of Windows and automatically add it to the GRUB boot menu, so you will be able to easily select the OS you want.

If your system uses legacy BIOS instead of UEFI, then the Windows installer has overwritten GRUB in the Master Boot Record, and you'll need to boot Linux from some external media to repair GRUB. One simple option for this is the [Boot-Repair CD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/). Another alternative is to boot from any live Linux media, and then mount your Linux partition, `chroot` into it, and then run `grub-install` as root to repair GRUB.